# iPhone error while importing .app into iTunes

Tags: iphone

My application tester has a problem while importing .mobileprovision file into iTunes. As I don't have the device I'm not able to check things out, here is the error message:

The provisioning profile "embedded.mobileprovision" could not be imported because an unknown error occurred (0xE800801A).

Any idea? He is trying to test on iPhone, if that helps.

Thanks,
XL

Answer (score 1):

Are you 100% sure that his device id is in that profile?

He might have to remove and re-install the profile from his iPhone in case he has an earlier version.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error two times:

- I tried to create an Ad Hoc Distribution of my app. When I installed the app through iTunes on a Windows XP machine I got the above error.

The file was zipped so the Exchange server should not be the problem anymore. I also tried it without the Exchange server. Always I got the same error message.

For the Ad Hoc version of the app I dragged the app and *.mobileprovision file separately on iTunes. And there was the error. Everytime I dragged the *.mobileprovision file the error message was displayed.

**Solution:** iTunes already had the newest version of the *.mobileprovision file (because I tried it many times before). So I only had to drag the app folder on iTunes and everything worked fine.

I don't understand why the replacing message was not shown (it was shown the first few times, but than the above error message occurred)

- I tried to install the distribution profile which I downloaded from the provisioning portal. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4156128/426227)) Thereby I dragged the *.mobileprovision again on iTunes. Than I got the error message without meaning.

**Solution:** So I didn't used iTunes for installing the profile. Instead I made a double click on the fresh downloaded certificate (Redownload of the distribution profile together with the WWDR certificate).

To help other people (who also get this error message) to find this topic I want provide the error message in another language:

> Das Bereitsstellungsprofil "xxx.mobileprovision" konnte nicht importiert werden, da ein unerwarteter Fehler aufgetreten ist (0xE800801A).

Nice spelling mistake in this error message ;)